# Vaadin AbstractJavaScriptComponent lifecycle

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I need to detect, on the client side, when my custom javascript component (extending `AbstractJavaScriptComponent` on the server side) is removed for any reason (for example a `Navigator` view change, ...) in order to do some cleanup.

To be more precise, the javascript component is implemented using ReactJS and I need to call `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(domContainerNode)` at the appropriate time to perform cleanup when the component is no longer necessary.

What is the best way to do this?  I couldn't find any information about lifecycle methods on the client-side connector wrapper.  I find it strange that the Vaadin team would have forgotten about this since I'm sure it's a common use case in an SPA in order not to leak memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best to keep this in the client if possible.

In your Javascript connector, set onUnregister to a callback function.

```
path_to_my_js_connector = function() {
    this.onUnregister = function () {
        // put your unmount code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thatt did not exist back then, it's indeed what I'm using now.

Comment: It still not documented in the 7.xxx pages.  AbstractJavaScriptConnector mentions it, but AbstractJavaScriptComponent does not.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I could issue an RPC call to the client side from `detach()`, but I'm not even sure this is a good idea.